# I wan to remove special characters and put same number of space between

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file of some special characters:

```
L$+M)jX];&?+jip=ZjJ#}^yV5;fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M`,pcII*6G<r
```

I wanted to remove some of the characters with a similar amount of space characters removed. remove this `fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M` I want to replace with a similar number of characters.

---

according to characters counter:

```
L$+M)jX];&?+jip=ZjJ#}^yV5;fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M`,pcII*6G<r
```

is 68 characters. I want to replace `fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M` with the same 30 characters of blank space.

Comment: I read this three times now and still have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: How do you define the term "special characters"? In your example of text to be removed, most characters are simply alphanumeric. Or do you mean "I want to remove a specific substring from a string and replace it with an equal amount of whitespace"?

Comment: Do you know the substring that you want to replace by spaces, or do you know the positions in the string that you want to replace by spaces, or do you have a pattern that matches the bit that you want to replace by spaces?

Comment: I have a huge text file of 10,0000+ characters in a single line(No break). Most of them contain fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M and similar lines with random characters. No pattern found. I tried to remove it with sed but it's not possible to remove all the characters from the file. I wanted to remove them all at the end I've to do it one by one. The sed command is not able to read them even the echo command is not printing those special text characters. How do I echo that string in bash and any way to skip all the unknown characters without using \(slash). Help

Comment: No, I don't know the position there are lots of string merged with a text file, having no space and line. The entire file is there in a single line. An example is shown below : Text$after$cat$fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/U9M$text$and$text$and$textfBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh(pw#^some$mmore#text%fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kD-r#$!7End File

Comment: Don't try to provide information in comments, [edit] your question to provide all of the information we need to be able to help you. It's still not at all clear what it is you're trying to do (remove a string? remove all characters listed in a string? something else?) so please also update your question to show the expected output given the sample input you provided.

Comment: [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/438143/geeta-prasad) you haven't accepted an answer to any of your questions so far. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for this. It is just a little bit tricky because you have a `'` in your pattern. This means you need to use `"` for the sed. Also, you have a `$`, which will need to be escaped so that `sed` doesn't see it as "end of line" and also, since we will be using double quotes, so that the shell doesn't see it as a variable. Finally, because you also have a `/`, we will need to use another character in the replacement operator. With all this in mind, this should do what you want:

```
$ sed "s:fBQ=\$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M:                              :" file
L$+M)jX];&?+jip=ZjJ#}^yV5;                              `,pcII*6G<r
```

For a more general solution, where you can pass any string in a variable and replace that, you could try something like this:

```
$ export var="fBQ=\$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M"
$ perl -pe '$f=quotemeta($ENV{var}); s/$f/" " x length($f)/e' file
L$+M)jX];&?+jip=ZjJ#}^yV5;                                        `,pcII*6G<r
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do - replace a string with blanks?

```
$ cat str
fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M

$ cat file
L$+M)jX];&?+jip=ZjJ#}^yV5;fBQ=$L+tG=#x4kDh('t%BWBG/P|U9M`,pcII*6G<r

$ awk 'NR==FNR{str=$0; lgth=length(str); next} s=index($0,str){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) sprintf("%*s",lgth,"") substr($0,s+lgth)} 1' str file
L$+M)jX];&?+jip=ZjJ#}^yV5;                              `,pcII*6G<r
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on all UNIX boxes for all characters in the string except newline.